# Why Websphere restarts my application every time is published?

Tags: websphere

I'm having the following problem: I'm using Rational Software Architect 7.5 and Websphere 7. Every time I publish (or automatic publishing takes place), Websphere re-starts my application. I think this is slowing down the publishing process. Is this the expected behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually you have a new version of an EAR file and hence the old one is replaced. Internally I guess that this is being by destroying the app's classloader and hence removing all the old classes from the server, then the new EAR is deployed and started.

As the new version of the app might have new intialisation parameters it's not unreasonable to reinitialise.

I assume that you have your server set to "run with resources in workspace" so the actual deployment step doesn't take very long. In my experience the publishing overhead is not too painful. The one thing that is annoying is when publishing is attempted when I am a making a sequence of edits that temporarily make the app unstartable. I have to remember to disable automatic publishing temporarily **and** remember to re-enable it.